# Implementing a CXF Web service using Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to expose a Code First Web service using Camel CXF Component. By assembling some of the available examples, I've come to the following route definition:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd">

    <bean id="productServiceImpl" class="com.demo.ws.CustomerServiceImpl" />

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <route>
            <from uri="cxf:bean:productServiceEndpoint" />

            <bean ref="productServiceImpl" />
            <!-- log input received -->
            <to uri="log:output" />
        </route>


    </camelContext>
    <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="productServiceEndpoint"
        address="http://localhost:9001/productService" serviceClass="com.demo.ws.CustomerService" />


</beans>
```

The SEI and implementation classes I'm using are trivial:

```
@WebService(serviceName="customerService")
public interface CustomerService 
{
    public String getCustomerById(String customerId);

}

public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService
{


    @Override
    public String getCustomerById(String customerId)
    {
         System.out.println("Called with "+customerId);
        return "Hello " +customerId;
    }
}
```

When running the project, the Webservice the implementation class is called correctly, returning the String "Hello [name]", however the returned body from SOAPUI is empty:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body/>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can you help me to produce the return value in the Response ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should return a SOAP message :

```
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
        SOAPBody body = soapMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getBody();

        QName payloadName = new QName("http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http/types", "greetMeResponse", "ns1");

        SOAPBodyElement payload = body.addBodyElement(payloadName);

        SOAPElement message = payload.addChildElement("responseType");

        message.addTextNode("Your custom message");
        return soapMessage;
```

You can also take a look to the camel doc examples : http://camel.apache.org/cxf-example.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had a look at the doc and the link. The main concern is that I have to create a payloadName for every method. I was wondering if the SOAP response could be generated automatically from the Web service (wrapping the return String in the message)

Comment: @user2824073 that would break SOA principles. Each method should be clearly defined and documented so that the generated WSDL can be used by developers with minimum effort. From my understanding based on your comment you want one method that will return a different answer? Please clarify